# Error con PreparedStatement

Tags: java

Mi problema es que me retorna un valor nulo,hay algun error en el preparedstatement que no me lo deja ejecutar y no puedo encontrar que es.

```
private final String CONSULTA_DATOS="SELECT * FROM ?";

public ResultSet getResultNegocio() {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
    PreparedStatement s=getConexionNegocio().prepareStatement(CONSULTA_DATOS);
    s.setString(1, "VENTA");
    
    return s.executeQuery();}
    
    catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error con la consulta preparada");}
    return null;}
```

Comment: No puedes pasar nombres de tablas en consultas preparadas, solamente valores de columnas o criterios de filtrado.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código no funcionará de ese modo porque **no se permite pasar nombres de tablas, de columnas, de bases de datos u otros como parámetros**, únicamente se pueden pasar parámetros para valores.

Si lo piensas bien, no tiene ningún sentido querer pasar como parámetro el nombre de la tabla `VENTAS` cuando lo puedes incorporar directamente a la consulta:

```
private final String CONSULTA_DATOS="SELECT * FROM VENTAS";
```

Y, si fuese una variable, igual, la concatenas a `CONSULTA_DATOS`  y listo.

Prueba así:

```
private final String CONSULTA_DATOS="SELECT * FROM VENTAS";

public ResultSet getResultNegocio() {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
    PreparedStatement s=getConexionNegocio().prepareStatement(CONSULTA_DATOS);
    
    return s.executeQuery();}
    
    catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error con la consulta preparada");}
    return null;}
```

Salvo otros errores, debería funcionar.