# Instruccion SQL con parametros

Tags: java, sql-server

Tengo que pasar una consulta pero los parametros quiero pasarselos tanto en el WHERE como el SELECT.
Algo asi:

```
 SELECT ? FROM tabla WHERE ? = ? AND TIPO=? AND LINEA=?
```

¿es eso siquiera posible?
De no ser. ¿Alguna idea?
Gracias

Comment: Que los _campos_ los puedas definir como un parámetro de un `PreparedStatement`? Lo dudo.

Comment: Yo también lo dudo, lo que si puedes, es crear dinamicamente el string de consulta

Comment: Eso no es posible, los `?` sólo sirven para marcar valores, no para marcas nombres de bases de datos, tablas o columnas, además no tendría ningún sentido, porque dichos valores puede ser sustituidos por variables. En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/376104/29967) he tratado de explicarlo.

Comment: Gracias a todos¡¡

Comment: sql dinámico es el camino. Puedes manejar en tu DAO el crear varios final String que puedas reusar en tus métodos para construir las consultas sobre las diferentes tablas con diferentes condiciones en el where, etc. Comienza a partir de la respuesta que enlaza @A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error con PreparedStatement](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376095/error-con-preparedstatement)

Answer (score 0):

yo llegue a hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
public void insertarCliente(Cliente e) throws ConsultasException {
        String sq = String.format("INSERT INTO cliente VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                e.getNif(), e.getNombre(), e.getApellido1(), e.getApellido2());
        this.consultaCliente(sq);
    }
```

Tuve que hacer un trabajo con conexión a  bases de datos y lo hice así.

No me acuerdo el motivo del porque pero funciona.

Te paso el enlace conto el programa que nos paso mi maestro se trata de un programa de gestion de productos y cliente : https://drive.google.com/file/d/15iZZOyPlCL8uV5WYusGNVVLHApN4MI2A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Los enlaces llegan a caducar es mejor publicar el código aquí y explicarlo

Comment: No se trata sólo de que funcione, sino también de que sea seguro, y tu código no lo es. Imagina que para Apellido2 alguien escribe esto: `Díaz; DELETE FROM unaTablaCualquiera;` tu consulta se ejecutaría inocentemente, porque tienes un código que es una puerta abierta a la *Inyección SQL*. El `DELETE` es de las cosas menos dañinas que podrían ocurrir, pues un usuario experimentado puede perpetrar ataques más dañinos por esa puerta abierta que has dejado en tu programa.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer **no es posible directamente** de la manera que lo has pensado.

Puedes (y debes) utilizar parámetros solamente para pasar **valores** al motor de base de datos, pero no puedes utilizar parámetros para pasar otras partes de la sentencia SQL que quieres ejecutar.

Pero, eso no significa que no pueda resolverse el tema, recordemos que estás en un lenguaje de programación (java en este caso) y que la sentencia SQL no es más que una cadena de caracteres.

De esta forma, puedes realizar la programación necesaria para **construir** una sentencia SQL y pasarla al motor, siempre que esta sea válida.  En otras palabras, una sentencia SQL no tiene por qué ser una constante escrita dentro de tu código, puede ser una construcción que tu mismo hagas. El cielo es el límite:

Imaginemos un caso hipotético donde voy construyendo una sentencia SQL donde, en base a un par de condiciones, decido si incluir algunos campos o algunas tablas en el SQL:

```java
public class so383141 {


    public static boolean getConDetalles() {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Boolean condicion1 = true;
            String miSentenciaSQL;
            miSentenciaSQL  = "select   a.campo1 \n";
            if (condicion1)
                miSentenciaSQL += "       , a.campo2 \n";
            if (getConDetalles())
                miSentenciaSQL += "       , b.campoDetalle \n";
            miSentenciaSQL += "  from miTabla1 a \n";
            if (getConDetalles())
                miSentenciaSQL += "       inner join miTabla2 b on b.Campo1 = a.Campo1 \n";
            miSentenciaSQL += " where a.CampoCondicion1 = ? \n";
            if (getConDetalles())
                miSentenciaSQL += "       and b.campo3 = ? \n";
            
            System.out.print(miSentenciaSQL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Si la variable `condicion1` es `true` y `getConDetalles()` devuelve `true`, la salida es:

```sql
select   a.campo1 
       , a.campo2 
       , b.campoDetalle 
  from miTabla1 a 
       inner join miTabla2 b on b.Campo1 = a.Campo1 
 where a.CampoCondicion1 = ? 
       and b.campo3 = ?
```

Ambas en `false` producen esta salida:

```sql
select   a.campo1 
  from miTabla1 a 
 where a.CampoCondicion1 = ?
```

Todas sus combinaciones producirán una sentencia SQL válida que puedo ejecutar en el motor de base de datos, como puedes comprobar por ti mismo si copias el código y juegas un poco con él.

No olvides, este es un pequeño ejemplo, con la potencia de un lenguaje de programación como java, puedes hacer millones de cosas, tan simples o tan complejas como puedas necesitar/imaginar.